# How to select the first <td>s on the left of <table> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

How to select the tds of the 1st column with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given HTML like this:

```
​<table>
  <tr><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

for example you can set the text of each first `td` in each row with this jQuery:

```
$("table tr td:first-child").text("hello");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```